# make .htaccess to prevent navigating to directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, server, wamp

I have this `.htaccess`

```
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule /?\.htaccess$ - [F,L]

# Remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /project/$1 [R,L]

# Map every link to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project/index.php.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/index.php?___MYROUTER=$1 [QSA,END]
```

but when I'm navigating to one of directories next to my `.htaccess` file like `css` folder in browser, with this address:

> http://localhost/project/css

then my address will be changes to:

> http://localhost/project/css?___MYROUTER=css&___MYROUTER=css&___MYROUTER=css&___MYROUTER=css&___MYROUTER=css&___MYROUTER=css&___MYROUTER=css&___MYROUTER=css&___MYROUTER=css&___MYROUTER=css

and in firefox this is the result:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> ```
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
> ```

but other addresses those are not pointing to an existing directory, will be ok like:

> http://localhost/project/mycontroller

this address is ok and will not be changed to anything else

**What is the problem with my `.htaccess`?**

this is my [log](http://omid.do.am/apache_error.log) file

Answer (score 0):

That is because Apache is adding a trailing slash in front of directories after `mod_dir` module has completed execution.

You can add a trailing slash in front of directories yourself using a separate rule.

```
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule /?\.htaccess$ - [F,L]

# Remove trailing slash for non directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /project/$1 [R,L]

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]


# Map every link to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ project/index.php?___MYROUTER=$1 [QSA,END]
```

Comment: Have you test it? I've tested it but it's not working properly. The directory issue is gone but still for directories `address?___MYROUTE=/css` showed up, I want this parameter to be hidden

Comment: Try my updated answer after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: if you can please come and see my apache through TeamViwer, how can I contact you directly? please save me from this :-( this is my telegram id http://t.me/omidgfx

Comment: So what problem are you still facing now? You can also add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` just before last `RewriteRule` as well.